# Scripting the Visual Studio editor?

Tags: visual-studio, vim, code-templates

I do use a templating tool for VS. I have used JustCode's and ReSharper's. But I find that often I could use something more dynamic.

Here is a trivial example:

Given the class

```
class Dog
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int NumLegs { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to convert it to:

```
class Dog
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int NumLegs { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }

    public Dog CloneMe()
    {
        return new Dog
        {
            Name = this.Name,
            NumLegs = this.NumLegs,
            Birthdate = this.Birthdate,
        };
    }
}
```

In the past I have just opened the file in Vim, and done it. I have also written ruby scripts to transform the file.

Both are a little cumbersome. Any suggestions on a tool designed for doing something like this?

Comment: I did realize that you can take a ruby script, and use it as an external command, and even redirect the the output to the visual studio Output window. This is actually really great, as I can hit CTRL+2 (or your shortcut of choice), see the output in the console, and then VS prompts me that the file has changed, and I get the processed file. Not sure if it gets any better than this, I even get to use my Ruby (or your lang of choice), without having to use a DSL, or learn a new tool/plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio has built-in "scripting" engine. For example, you can find properties of the selected class in the editor with (DTE.ActiveWindow.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection).ActivePoint.CodeElement[vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass] as EnvDTE.CodeClass and you can write to the current edit point in the VS editor with DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.

Comment: Are you talking about a VB macro? That has been removed in 2013.

Comment: For lightweight automation you can use my Visual Commander extension. (VS 2013 also still supports full add-ins and extensions.)

Comment: This looks like what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried VsVim?
Its a plugin for visual studio which transforms the editor into a vim
editor. 
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329

Comment: I have tried it multiple times, but I find using Vim as an external tool works better.